# Design pattern for minimizing cache hits on dependent services

Tags: java, caching, guice

I need to get data dependent on multiple service calls, e.g.

```
getInsurancyPrice(id, priceType) {
    // any call of this method can throw a "NotFoundException"

    user = getUser(id);
    car = getCar(user);
    insurancyCompany = getInsurancyCompany(user, car);
    price = getPrice(insurancyCompany, priceType);

    return price;
}
```

Since those calls can be costly and are unlikely to change, I wanna use a cache (with some expiration time).

Ideally, I want getInsurancyPrice(1, 1) to go fetch everything needed on the first call and return the same thing as the first call on all further calls (even if it was a NotFoundException - ie negative cache)

There's another detail:
Let's say I call getInsurancyPrice(1, 2) after calling getInsurancyPrice(1, 1)... There's no reason to run the first 3 calls of the method, since they don't depend on "priceType" (so I should already have insurancyCompany cached). I'd like to have only the getPrice() method called in that case with the precomputed values
I'm trying to avoid having getUser() and getCar() even hitting a cache, since I could skip directly to the getInsurancyCompany() call from the cache

I can think on ways to do that using a lot of "if"'s in a terrible design.. but is there some better design pattern that could assist me?

Comment: Do you really need to load the whole user and car to get insurance company? If it's enough to have user and car ids to get insurance company and price you should avoid getUser and getCar calls.

Comment: Hi, sorry to not make it clear. This is just a mock example to try to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Guava's LoadingCache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html). This does expiration time and a whole lot more besides.

Use one cache instance for each call you make. Use simple composite object as a key for the methods that take multiple arguments, so you can pass them through to the loader.

For the second part, I would avoid worrying hitting caches unnecessarily. The whole point of this kind of cache is that it's very fast if there's a hit - orders of magnitude faster than a DB call or an HTTP call to some external system. Just hit the cache.

Comment: Agreed, simply create four caches, one for every call (as long as space is not an issue). Only make sure that you configure your caches independently, e.g. different expiration times, eviction policies, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to minimize hitting cache because this is a distributed server and the cache wouldn't be local. It's still fast (I'm guessing about ~5ms or so), but minimizing seems reasonable.